# Dimension of assembled bilinear forms in fenics

Tags: python, assemble, fenics

I'm new to stackoverflow and fenics. I recently used the env to compute input code for another file.

I want to calculate finite elements and save the assembled matrices, say over a rectangle domain `D=(-1,1)*(-2,2)`. I set the number of discretising points in direction of `x`and `y`, setting `nx,ny=9`, i.e. `2*10*10` triangles.

when I calculate the matrices and assemble them they have the size `(nx+1)*(ny+1)*(nx+1)*(ny+1)` instead of `(nx+1)*(ny+1)`.

MWE:

```
from dolfin import *
import numpy as np

# Mesh and function space
# mesh (generates 2*nx*ny number of triangles) and function space
# number of FEM = (nx+1)*(ny+1) = 100
# matrixSize = (nx+1)*(ny+1) * (nx+1)*(ny+1) = 100*100
nx = 9
ny = 9
# mesh dims
x = [-1, 1]
y = [-2, 2]
mesh = RectangleMesh(Point(x[0], y[0]), Point(x[1], y[1]), nx, ny)
V = FunctionSpace(mesh, "CG", 1)

# Time variables
dt = Constant(0.3)

g_expr = 'alpha'
g = Expression(g_expr , alpha=0.0, degree=2)

u0 = interpolate(g, V)

# Variational problem
u = TrialFunction(V)
v = TestFunction(V)
f = Expression('-exp(-(pow(x[0], 2)+pow(x[1], 2)))', degree=2)

a = u*v*dx + dt*inner(grad(u), grad(v))*dx
L = u0*v*dx + dt*f*v*dx
bc = DirichletBC(V, g, "on_boundary")

A = assemble(a)
print(A.array())
# print the sizes of row and col space of assembled matrix A (both = 100)
print((len(A.array()), len(A.array()[0])))
```

I'd appreciate any help, thx!

Comment: Ah, I committed a fallacy in reasoning.
The code above is correct and giving the correct results.

The FE that are generated are of course `100`, that's right.
But in order to compute the Matrix I have now vectors of length `100` to multiply with each other, which results in a Matrix of `100 *100`